# Magento 2.4 how to create a custom region select at checkout

Tags: checkout, uicomponent, shipping-address, country-regions, uielement

Good morning, does anyone know how I can create a custom selection in the checkout of the type "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region" something like the default selection of "region" that contains all the departments/provinces of a country?
I'm trying with PHP with LayuotProcessor, but I can't get the select to list the departments, the select is created, but it doesn't contain options.

I appreciate your help

[image]